# Where to post questions asking "is my solution correct"?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Lets say I have code which behaved differently than expected. I couldn't find explanation of this behavior in documentation or tutorial but I somehow managed to solve it (at least it looks that way, since error doesn't appear any more) but I am not sure if my solution is correct and if it doesn't introduce another problems.

So I want to know three things:

- why problem occurred
- which part of documentation/tutorial did I miss
- was my solution correct

Where should I ask this question to get all these informations? I was thinking about:

- [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - since I have code which *seems to be working* and I am looking for review, but then I am not sure if I will be able to get all informations that I need
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) - since I am looking for cause of problem (preferably with information from specification)
- any other site?

Or maybe I should ask two questions:

- one on SO where I will ask general question about problem
- second on CR where I will ask about my solution

Is such solution acceptable?

Comment: [Completely relevant meme](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/A6PSWTFCUAI7N-5.jpg).

Comment: If your solution is correct but your code doesn't behave as expected, you have an odd definition of "correct" :-)

Comment: I am always suspicious when my code works first time.

Comment: @Bergi Actually this question is more about solution which seems to be working now, but it was created by pressing random keys on keyboards (you can say my cat/dog/snake/spider/fish walked over it few times) and now new code seems to be working. So i think it is reasonable to ask if this new code is *correct* (and if my pet is better programmer than me :-)

Comment: @Pshemo: [Walking fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walking_fish)? [Underwater keyboard](http://www.engadget.com/2004/03/07/underwater-bluetooth-keyboard/)? I'm impressed.

Comment: @Bergi Nah it was simpler case. Because of stress caused by this bug I threw my wireless keyboard somewhere. It just happened that [it landed in the fish tank](http://inventorspot.com/files/images/Logitech_Keyboard_in_a_fish_tank.img_assist_custom.jpg) (I bough waterproof keyboard expecting that day like this can happen).

Comment: Code Review will analyze your code and as a byproduct probably explain why things didn't happen the way you expected, I'd go there.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You have two completely different questions here.  You have one question asking for an explanation of why something wasn't behaving as expected.  You then have a completely different question asking for the solution you've provided to be evaluated.

The first question is on topic on SO.  Simply describe the situation and explain that you're looking for an explanation of why the code is behaving the way that it is, and that you're not looking for a solution to the problem because you already have one.  You can provide your solution if you want, it's likely to give others some insight into what the underlying problem is.  You could phrase the question along the lines of, "why does [code block 1] (your non-working code) behave like this, while [code block 2] (your working code) behave in this other way; I expected [explanation of what you thought each block should do].

The second question is on topic on CR.  Here you should just be describing the problem, showing your solution, and describing what feedback you're interested in, rather than looking for explanations as to why each code block does what it does.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So variant with two similar but not same questions on two different sites is OK. That is what I wanted to hear :)

Comment: @Pshemo The only thing I would add to this is that I think it would be better to wait until you get an answer on SO before posting anything on CR. The answer you get on SO might resolve your confusion enough that the CR post becomes unnecessary.

Comment: I agreed at the beginning that there's a question "why something wasn't behaving as expected". But then you don't say that the question, to be clear, has to contain what they expected. Moreover to be adequately researched it should say why they expect that--otherwise they're asking for yet another explanation of something easily searched for. And that is going to be where the error is. Not in the code.

Comment: @philipxy Sure, the question would indeed need to be well researched, and meet all of the other criteria of a good question on the site.  My point here is that by approaching your question from the perspective of wanting to know why a certain snippet has a given behavior, rather than wanting to know if a given solution is "a good solution", you at least are on the right track for *starting* to form your question.  It also needs to be well researched, clearly written, appropriately scoped, etc.  It's just gotten past the one problem brought up here of being opinion based.