# Is asking: "is this explanation correct?" an acceptable question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Would it be inappropriate to ask a question of the form:

> "I've been learning about concept `x`.  If I understand it correctly, concept `x` can be simply defined as `"..."` and it fits into framework `y` this way.
> Is any of what I've just stated wrong?`

?

**UPDATE:**

*Due to some of the discussion in the comments, I'm providing an example question:*

I'm trying to gain a deeper understanding of the Ruby on Rails framework and I've been doing a lot of googling about terms I've heard thrown around but never understood.

Two of these terms were "ActionPack" and "Rack"

According to the docs for each of these:

#### ActionPack:

> Action Pack is a framework for handling and responding to web requests. It provides mechanisms for routing (mapping request URLs to actions), defining controllers that implement actions, and generating responses by rendering views, which are templates of various formats. In short, Action Pack provides the view and controller layers in the MVC paradigm.

#### Rack:

> Rack provides a minimal interface between webservers that support Ruby and Ruby frameworks.

If I understand correctly, Rack is `x` and works with rails in `such-and-such` a way. But ActionPack has more to do with `...` and works in `such-and-such` a way.
So the request would go:
`Client HTTP request --> Rack --> Server --> ActionPack etc.`

Is this correct?  Or have I misunderstood? Because the two seem very similar to me. (As in, they both handle User HTTP related data before it gets to the rest of rails)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to post questions asking "is my solution correct"?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297707/where-to-post-questions-asking-is-my-solution-correct)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I'm not overly enthusiastic about that dupe. I don't think that one matches

Comment: The linked question is not a duplicate.  It's asking two questions in one, and it's about asking for a code explanation (and which SE site to post it on) rather than a validation of understanding a concept correctly.

Comment: @rene Fair enough. I'm sure someone's asked this question before though...

Comment: Quite similar to [“Explain X to me” questions: How to react?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271468/215552), and the answer is going to be similar: depends. Could be too broad, could be okay. Generally, the answer to such a question could be "sort of; in these edge cases, your definition of x is not quite right". If there's a lot of those cases, it could get pretty broad.

Comment: Re: your update. That sounds like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: Users have lots of tricks to prevent their question getting closed as a dup.  Such a question is almost certainly "too localized", can't close them anymore for that reason.  Imagine the massive variety of versions of that question you could ask.  Maybe you make something constructive out of it that isn't also subjective, I generally don't bother.  These programmers need to bounce off their ideas with team members, having the option to do it anonymously is too attractive.

Comment: @Hans Not all of us have the luxury of a team. Or a job for that matter.

Comment: Or know how to program.  These reasons never once made a question on topic.

Answer (score 7):

I would say this really depends on what this concept `x` is in this equation. I could see two problems:

1. `X` is a rather large concept => The question will probably be closed as too broad since a full explanation would be too long for SO's answer format.
2. `X` is a very simple concept => There is a high chance that the concept has been explained in an answer already, so your question might get closed as a duplicate.

If you can make sure that these points won't apply to your question I'd say it's fine.

*(Unless there is some strict policy that deals with these types of questions that I'm not aware of)*

The optimal scenario would be that there are only minor mistakes (if at all) in your own explanation, which people could point out and correct in relatively short answers without having to explain the whole concept from the ground up. So you should optimally be pretty sure about most of your explanation already, in order to avoid the risk of your question getting closed as too broad.

Answer (score 6):

In most cases, such questions are no different from "here's my code, it doesn't work, so tell me what's wrong" questions. Those kinds of questions are essentially about getting someone to go through every line of your code and seeing if it's doing what you wanted it to.

This is the same thing, only with a process/algorithm rather than code. You list out your "understanding", and you ask if there's something wrong. So we have to read through it, and if any one part of that process process is wrong, we have to explain why.

Such questions should not be encouraged. If you don't feel confident in your understanding of something, then unless you can pinpoint exactly where you feel confused, then you're not ready to ask a question here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of asking "Is what I explained wrong?" try to ask "How to explain this?". At the end of the day, you don't know if your explanation is right (if you knew it was right, you wouldn't be asking the question in first place), in which case the most productive course of action is to say that you don't know how to explain it. You can include your attempt at explaining X, and why you think it's not a good explanation to give context, which could narrow the scope of your question and make sure people focus in what "you don't know" part. That would give you one of two things:

1. A better explanation of what you are trying to explain.
2. Pointers about how you can make your explanation better. (and maybe learn allow someone to teach something useful in the process)

Of course, the thing you are explaining has to be something only software developers can explain. For pure theoretical questions, it would be better to look at other sites instead.

Comment: I think it is crucial to include an attempt. Without it, it is either too broad or unclear. Does this mean that no code is needed to have a decent question?

Comment: @rene sometimes using code to give context about what you are attempting to do, could help others to figure out what are you doing wrong, but in theory you could literally spell out the code in english (a la rubber duck) and have a good question.

Comment: @Braiam I appreciate you taking the time to write an answer.  I think though, that asking "How to explain this?" would defeat the purpose of my question.  I'm not asking _how_ to explain something.  I _think_ I know how, and I hope to know what I'm talking about because I just researched the concept, but I want to be sure that the model I've made of the concept sitting in my head is correct by asking more experienced programmers.

Comment: @0112 Why aren't you confident that your explanation is correct? Maybe that is what you should be asking about.

Comment: @braiam I'm "underconfident", because I just spent the past 2.5 hours reading about it online, and I want to clarify that the way I've just understood it is correct.

Answer (score -1):

I usually encourage the user to edit their question to be more specific, because clearly the person has some reason to think that their explanation might be wrong. If the user doesn't reply, I vote to close the question as unclear.

If the answer to the question is "yes, that's correct", and a Google search can easily find an article about the subject, I see no reason in having an SO post about it. I wouldn't vote to close the question, but I would probably downvote it for lack of research.

If the answer to the question is "no, that's wrong", then I would consider if the topic is too borad, and if it's not I will answer.